# Master Unicorn process is terminating and starting new workers all the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, unicorn, whenever-capistrano

Like I wrote in the title Unicorn master process is lately (after deploy and restarting) is killing workers and starting new ones all the time and that is why my Rails app is not working at all. Besides that the CPU on the server is 100% during that. However if I make cap unicorn:stop everytning is being shutdown correctly but after cap unicorn:start it starts all over again.

unicorn.rb:

```
# Should be 'production' by default, otherwise use other env 
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'

app_path = "/home/ruby/app/current"

listen 5000
# Spawn unicorn master worker for user ruby (group: www-data)
user 'ruby', 'ruby'
working_directory app_path

worker_processes 2
timeout 90
#preload_app true

# Log everything to one file
stderr_path "log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "log/unicorn.log"

# Set master PID location
pid "#{app_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

# To save some memory and improve performance
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

# Force the bundler gemfile environment variable to   
# reference the Сapistrano "current" symlink
before_exec do |_|
   ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = File.join(@app, 'Gemfile')
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
 # Replace with MongoDB or whatever
 if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from ActiveRecord')
 end

 old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end

  sleep 1
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # Replace with MongoDB or whatever
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to ActiveRecord')
  end
```

end

and my deploy.rb

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
require 'rvm/capistrano'
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"
set :default_shell, :bash
set :rvm_type, :system
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3-p194'
set(:rvm_path)          { "/usr/local/rvm" }

set :application, "investwallet"

# main details
role :web, "example.com"
role :app, "example.com"
role :db, "example.com"

# server details
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :deploy_to, "/home/ruby/app"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :user, "ruby"
set :use_sudo, false
set :port, 22

# repo details
set :scm, :git
set :scm_username, "git"
#set :scm_passphrase, ""  # The deploy user's password
set :repository, "git@example.com:/opt/git/example.git"
set :branch, "master"
#set :git_enable_submodules, 1
set :keep_releases, 3

set(:releases_path)     { File.join(deploy_to, version_dir) }
set(:shared_path)       { File.join(deploy_to, shared_dir) }
set(:current_path)      { File.join(deploy_to, current_dir) }
set(:release_path)      { File.join(releases_path, release_name) }

default_environment["RAILS_ENV"] = 'production'

require 'capistrano-unicorn'

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_db'
after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_letter_opener'
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
after 'deploy:restart', 'unicorn:reload' # app IS NOT preloaded
after 'deploy:restart', 'unicorn:restart'  # app preloaded

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Symlinks the database.yml"
  task :symlink_db, :roles => :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #      {release_path}/config/database.yml"
 end

  desc "Symlinks the tmp letter opener"
  task :symlink_letter_opener, :roles => :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/letter_opener/ #{release_path}/tmp/letter_opener"
 end
```

end

```
namespace :unicorn do
  desc "Restart Unicorn"
  task :restart do
    unicorn.stop
    unicorn.start
  end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

try `bundle install`
the chances are you have included a gem and have not installed it.